# OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 203-02-19 00:00:00

Tags: python, pandas

First of all I extracted from my database only the date part then i convert it into the pandas data frame. Now when i am trying to convert the date which is in the object format, it showing some sort of out of bounds nanosecond error.

Below is the code:

```
mydata['Inv_Net_Due_Date_new'] = pd.to_datetime(mydata['Inv_Net_Due_Date_new'],format='%Y-%m')
```

Error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 203-02-19 00:00:00
```

Comment: Due to the **nanosecond** precision pandas cannot represent all timestamps. `pd.Timestamp.min` is `Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')`. Your date has year 203 which is a problem. Is that a typo, or do you truly have the year 203, in which case there are [other alternatives](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob).

Comment: Actually its a huge dataset and there would be issues as you notified.. is there a way to solve it

Comment: I am using this Left(Inv_Net_Due_Date,9) to get only the date part from db.. is this the problem